# cannot unpack non-iterable bool object(when trying to filter result for user registered in auth>User module)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I’m creating a django based web app and I have used `Auth > User` model (without any customization except password hiding) and for user detail I have created another model `ChangeShift`. and model based form.

Case 1: When I am using `alluser = ShiftChange.objects.all()` I'm able to see all the data available in `ShiftChange` model.

Case 2: Now I want that when user is logging, he should be able to see data related to his name and I'm using this:

```
def retrieve_view(request):
    # alluser = ShiftChange.objects.all()
    alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(ShiftChange.ldap_id == request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'apple/shift2.html', {'alluser': alluser})
```

For this code I am getting error:

```
cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

Error Traceback:

```
[21/Sep/2020 11:13:18] "GET /static/css/auth.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1662
Internal Server Error: /alldata/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/shaileshyadaav/djangoshaileshdurga/mapsIT/apple/views.py", line 53, in retrieve_view
    alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(ShiftChange.ldap_id == request.user.username)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1255, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(
    ShiftChange.ldap_id == request.user.username)
```

is the error. The part `ShiftChange.ldap_id == request.user.username` is an expression that evaluates to `True` or `False`, and then your code becomes equivalent to

```
alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(True)
```

or

```
alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(False)
```

and that is probably not what you want.

Try using a single `=` sign and use a valid left side kwarg (because `ShiftChange.ldap_id` with the dot in the middle is not valid here).
So your code may end up similar to this:

```
alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(ldap_id=request.user.username)
```

Comment: Thank you! for the help. after Changing above line Now it is working as expected.